# grails 1.3.7 + 2.0, section 5.2.1.1, Many-to-one and one-to-one

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

[Section 5.2.1.1](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.2.1.1%20Many-to-one%20and%20one-to-one) has examples A - C, which seem a bit confusing:

Example B:  Is this still a many-to-1 relationship, like Example A (i.e. same table setup)?  At the end it says, "to make a true one-to-one, use the hasOne property ...".

Example C:  when hasOne is used, should belongsTo no longer be used?  Is it implied?

Why do they show two variations in Example C?  Is the first one prone to problems?

I'm trying to understand all the valid Many-to-1 and One-to-One combos.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I agree their terminology is a little confusing here.  But I'll try to help:

### Many-to-one (A)

What they are referring to here is a relationship where the parent object points to a single child object.  The child object, however, has no knowledge of the parent relationship.  The reason (I believe) they are calling this a many-to-one is that a unique one-to-one mapping is not enforced.  Technically, the same *Nose* could be used on multiple *Faces* just by saving them to the relationship.  And, if you delete a *Face*, the *Nose* continues to exist, just without a face.  *(This is getting weird to write!)*

### One-to-one stored on the Parent table (B)

In the second example, they have added the `belongsTo` to enforce a one-to-one relationship.  This means that the existence of a *Nose* depends on the existence of a *Face*.  So, now it is a true *one-to-one* relationship.  The foreign key for this relationship is stored on the *Face* table, due to the way it is configured (see the next section).

### One-to-one stored on the Child table (C)

In the last example, it's still one-to-one.  However, changing the simple `Nose nose` to `static hasOne = [nose:Nose]` has moved the foreign key over to the *Nose* table.  In this case, you use the `belongsTo` because each *Nose* can only be related to a single *Face*.

### In Summary

- A simple assignment `Model model` creates a single, unidirectional relationship to the child.  The child has no direct way to reference the parent relationship, and in fact, may be related to multiple parent models.
- A bi-directional one-to-one assignment requires the child to `belongTo` it's parent, which also enforces data integrity through cascading.
- A bi-directional one-to-one stored on the child is created by configuring the parent to have one (`hasOne`) child model.

Hopefully this helps a little.  (I still think the *Many-to-one* terminology is awkward.)

Comment: Thanks for your response OverZealous. I wish comments supported carriage returns.  In Ex B: why do you think they make that statement at the end of example B, i.e. "to make relationship a true one-to-one"?  In Ex C, why don't they have a combo using both a hasOne and a belongsTo?

Comment: I'm thinking B is still a Many-to-1, but now with Cascade in place for the save and delete.  However, one could shoot themselves in the foot with this, as if let's say there is class X and class Y, and x1 references y1, and x2 references y1.  Then deleting x1 would delete y1, and so x2 would be "in trouble" (as y1 is gone).

Comment: Sounds like you figured it out a little better than I did!

Comment: Not really OverZealous -- I'm still confused and I appreciate your thoughts, which are helpful.  I'm going to post a question, regarding whether hasOne and belongsTo should be used together.

Comment: Ugh -- I've spent another hour reading this stuff, to find what appears to be a definite inconsistency in the Grails docs, namely, in the section we are talking about, where 1) in example C it is said "this property puts the foreign key on the inverse table from the previous example", and 2) the very last code snippet in [belongsTo](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/belongsTo.html), and its discussion about how back references are created.  Example B uses the "static belongsTo = [face:Face], which the belongsTo doc says will create a back reference.